# Windows Service not send but windows form Yes

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, webclient

I have a Windows form and a Windows form who runs the same code, the both do the same. They download some files from a pc on Lan (with windows7 embeded) and send it to a selected server.

The problem is if I send it by windows form works well and send the files without problems but if leave the windows server send the data automatically have a problem when try to download the files fails I try it on some pc and works (windows form and windows service) but I find some pc fails (windows form works and service fail), and don’t download the files and I see the log from program and see this fails:

-Unable to connect to remote server.

-The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy authentication required (In that case the system of that office have a proxy for all traffic from internet but the connection is on Lan first).

I find the error on the next function:

```
string xmlText = "";
// Read the file as a string
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    xmlText = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

That function download a XML from the Lan PC.

Any one know how solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your are running as an unknown user, you need to run as your user (or set user/password).

Try this:

```
string xmlText = "";
// Read the file as a string
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    xmlText = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

And then running the service under your account.
If you dont want to run under your account you need to set the user and password in the code:

```
string xmlText = "";
// Read the file as a string
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    xmlText = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try to connect to the pc and change version.